# BGTask running while iPad is awake--how is this possible?

Tags: ios, background-task, bgtaskscheduler, bgprocessingtask

We have been using the `BGTask` (specifically a `BGProcessingTask`) reliably for the last couple of years for our app. Up until now they wake up automatically while the screen is off, the iPad is plugged in, and the app is running (that is, in the background), but never while the screen is on (that is, never when the `scenePhase == .active`). For the last month or so, I've noticed that they are triggering now while the screen is displayed. How is this possible??? Did something change with a recent version of iOS? It's violating Apple's own documentation, which describes the `BGProcessingTask` as:

> "A time-consuming processing task that runs while the app is in the background."